# Truncate an CSV column using CsvKit

Tags: csv, csvkit

How can I truncate the length of a column using CSVKit?

The definition looks like this:

- Column 1: no length restriction
- Column 2: <no more than 2 characters>

This should properly handle escaped (quoted) columns and new lines.

For example:

```
First Header,Second Header
foo,
foo,b
foo,bar
foo,"bar"
foo,"""bar"
foo,"
bar"
```

should become

```
First Header,Second Header
foo,
foo,b
foo,ba
foo,ba
foo,"""b"
foo,"
b"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution with csvsql:

```
csvsql -d ',' --query 'SELECT "First Header" as "First Header",substr("Second Header",1,2) as "Second Header" FROM data' data.txt
```

```
First Header,Second Header
foo,
foo,b
foo,ba
foo,ba
foo,"""b"
foo,"
b"
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [r_31415's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709891/116858), but without having to name any other field than the field that we want to modify or remembering the order of the fields (also similar to [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709884/116858) in that respect):

```bash
csvsql --query 'UPDATE stdin SET "Second Header" = substr("Second Header",1,2); SELECT * FROM stdin' <file
```

---

A slightly more flexible approach which allows us to slot in any JSON-capable tool to do the needed transformations on the data:

1. Using `csvjson` from csvkit to create a JSON array of the CSV data.
2. Using `jq` to read the JSON data, and to truncate the `Second Header` values at two characters.
3. Using `in2csv` from csvkit to read the JSON and to create CSV.

```bash
csvjson file | jq 'map(."Second Header" |= .[:2])' | in2csv -f json
```

The output of `csvjson`, given the CSV data in the question, is the equivalent of

```json
[
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": null
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "b"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "bar"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "bar"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "\"bar"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "\nbar"
  }
]
```

The output of `jq` would then be

```json
[
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": null
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "b"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "ba"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "ba"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "\"b"
  },
  {
    "First Header": "foo",
    "Second Header": "\nb"
  }
]
```

And the final output:

```
First Header,Second Header
foo,
foo,b
foo,ba
foo,ba
foo,"""b"
foo,"
b"
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't think it was directly possible with CSVKit, until shown [otherwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709891/100397). However, I do know that it can be done with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/):

```
mlr --csv put '${Second Header} = substr(${Second Header},0,1)' file.csv
```

Output

```
First Header,Second Header
foo,
foo,
foo,ba
foo,ba
foo,"""b"
foo,"
b"
```

(If you're using Miller version 6 or later there are better and preferred alternatives to `substr`. I can't test them here so I won't include them.)